# How can I add model binding support for a new non-complex type?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a controller action that takes a parameter of a custom type:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(CustomType someValue)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The custom type is not known by ASP.NET MVC, and it is not a "complex" type; it needs custom creation logic:

```
public class CustomType
{
    public CustomType(string data){}
}
```

In this example, I would like to be able to tell ASP.NET MVC that whenever it needs to bind to a `CustomType`, it should use the following procedure:

```
(string someRequestValue) => new CustomType(someRequestValue)
```

I've had a quick look around here and Google, but I didn't find anything that covered this simple scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [Leo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21037385/238753), this can be done by implementing `IModelBinder` and registering the implementation for `CustomType`. That implementation can be improved by supporting any action parameters rather than only parameters with a specific name. I've also added null-checking so that the behaviour is consistent with the built-in model binding.

#### Model Binder

```
public class CustomTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(valueName);
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        var textValue = value.AttemptedValue;
        return new CustomType(textValue);
    }
}
```

#### Registration

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CustomType), new CustomTypeModelBinder());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bart's answer is quite valid and I think it suits your case scenario. Yet, if you ever need to change the default model binding behaviour, it'd be good to implement your own model binder object by implementing the `IModelBinder` interface which exposes one single method `BindModel`

```
public class CustomTypeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueReceived = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("actionParam").AttemptedValue;
        return new CustomType(valueReceived);
    }
}
```

Then it's just a matter of registering the model binder when your application starts...

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
       ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(CustomType), new CustomTypeModelBinder());
}
```

But, as stated above, you don't really need to go down this path...I think

Comment: you beat me by a min ;) Nice one!

Comment: Oops...sorry mate :)...who cares anyway? As long as there's enough and meaningful contribution to the community of developers out there ;)

Comment: Yak... reading your comment, i thought to press Like button LOL.. habit from other social networking site...

Comment: Thanks! It looks like your implementation will only work if the action parameter is called *actionParam*. How can it be implemented so it's only dependent on `CustomType` rather than a specific parameter?

Comment: Never mind my last comment; I've found out how to do it myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

why not :

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string someValue)
    {
        var obj = new CustomType(someValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I want my action logic to be concise and focused on the actual logic rather than infrastructure.

Comment: Also, I expect to use `CustomType` in multiple action methods, and I don't want to clutter them with duplicated model binding logic.